# init class from another class swift

Tags: swift, class, init

I have this `ScreenSecurityWorker`

```
final class ScreenSecurityWorker {
    
    weak var delegate: ScreenSecurityWorkerDelegate?
    private var isPassPhraseOn: Bool { return SettingsManager.shared.load(.passPhrase) }
    private var isPassPhraseForced: Bool { return environment.forcePassPhraseEnabled }
    
    var screenSecurityEnabled = false
```

inside my `Mainrouter` I am changing `screenSecurityEnabled` bool value to true at `activateScreenSecurity`

```
func activateScreenSecurity() {
        guard !screenSecurityWorker.passwordSecurityInProgress else { return }
        screenSecurityVC = ScreenSecurityBuiler.make()
        app.dismissKeyboardOnTopVC()
        app.window.rootViewController = screenSecurityVC
        screenSecurityWorker.passPhareSuccess = false
        screenSecurityWorker.screenSecurityEnabled = true
    }
```

I am trying to reach to `screenSecurityEnabled` from `ChatVC`

but if I init it as

```
let screenSecurityWorker = ScreenSecurityWorker()
```

it has no values inside at all.

if I try like this it gives error

```
let screenSecurityWorker : ScreenSecurityWorker?
    
    init(screenSecurityWorker: ScreenSecurityWorker){
        self.screenSecurityWorker = screenSecurityWorker
    }
```

I need this `screenSecurityWorker.screenSecurityEnabled` to change subviews in this function inside `ChatVC`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if screenSecurityWorker!.screenSecurityEnabled {
            let place = chatTextAreaContainerView.bounds.height + CGFloat(lastContentOffset ?? collectionView.contentOffset.y - chatTextAreaContainerView.bounds.height)
            self.collectionView.contentOffset.y = place
            screenSecurityWorker!.screenSecurityEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: What’s the error you are getting?

Comment: 'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer inside init(screenSeucirtyWorker: and if I add super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) I get fatal error

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `ScreenSecurityWorker` in `ChatVC`, it'ts not the same one from the one in `MainRouter`. it's like having in one ViewController `let myStr = String()`, and in another ViewController `let myStr = String()`. They aren't the same instance, and you did the same when doing `ScreenSecurityWorker()`. If you didn't override the `description`, printing them might output `<ScreenSecurityWorker:0xsomeValue>` where `someValue` is their address, and they should be different.

Comment: var screenSecurityWorker : ScreenSecurityWorker! is causing viewDidLayoutSubviews to fatal error Unexpectedly found nil

Comment: You usually want to avoid the trailing ! On your variables. You could pass in a shared security worker in an initializer or you could create a “shared instance” and access it globally.